# How to remove git mac os x

Tags: mac-osx, git

I've installed git on my mac, but I don't know how to completly remove it, because I want to reinstall it again...any tips?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git /etc/paths.d/git /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you installed it.

Places to look for git:

INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local in my case (perhaps /opt/local or something else)

- INSTALL_PREFIX/git/
- INSTALL_PREFIX/bin/git*
- INSTALL_PREFIX/libexec
- INSTALL_PREFIX/share

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Git from code.google.com, you can follow the [official uninstall instructions](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/wiki/Uninstall):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git /etc/paths.d/git /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

If you installed it through the [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) package manager, you can remove git with:

```
fink remove git
```